# Latent Vectors of my VAE contain the value inf and -inf?

Tags: neural-networks, keras, autoencoders

I have implemented a VAE and trained it on images. After training and looking at the loss and reconstructions I thought the training was successful.

But then I displayed my latent vectors and saw that it contains very big numbers and also the value inf and -inf.

Is this normal or did my training go wrong?

For the VAE I used the Keras example as a base and changed the layer architecture to my needs.

My Implementation:

```
class Sampling(layers.Layer):
    """Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

latent_dim = 100 #sehr wichtig 

encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3)) 
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 4, strides=2, padding="same")(encoder_inputs)   
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=1, padding="same")(x)   
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3,strides=1, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 4,strides=2, padding="same")(x)  
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3,strides=1, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3,strides=1, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(100, 8,strides=1, padding="valid")(x)        
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
encoder_test = x
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder_t1 =  keras.Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_test, name="encoder_test")
encoder_t2 =  keras.Model(encoder_inputs, z_mean, name="encoder_test")
encoder_t3 =  keras.Model(encoder_inputs, z_log_var, name="encoder_test")
encoder_t4 =  keras.Model(encoder_inputs, z, name="encoder_test")
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
encoder.summary()

latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = layers.Reshape((1, 1, latent_dim))(latent_inputs)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(latent_dim, 8, strides=1, padding="valid")(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, strides=1, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, strides=1, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, 4, strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, strides=1, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, strides=1, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 4, strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)

decoder_outputs = layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
decoder.summary()

class VAE(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, encoder_t1, encoder_t2, encoder_t3, encoder_t4, **kwargs):
        super(VAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.encoder_t1 = encoder_t1
        self.encoder_t2 = encoder_t2
        self.encoder_t3 = encoder_t3
        self.encoder_t4 = encoder_t4
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(
            name="reconstruction_loss"
        )
        self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")


    def train_step(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            data = data[0]
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = encoder(data)
            reconstruction = decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(    
                keras.losses.mse(data, reconstruction)      #binary_crossentropy
            )
            reconstruction_loss *= 32 * 32                                   
            kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(kl_loss)      
            kl_loss *= -0.5 
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)
        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }
    def call(self, inputs):
      z_mean, z_log_var, z = encoder(inputs)
      reconstruction = decoder(z)
      reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
          keras.losses.mse(inputs, reconstruction)
      )
      reconstruction_loss *= 32 * 32
      kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
      kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(kl_loss)      #mean
      kl_loss *= -0.5 
      total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
      self.add_metric(kl_loss, name='kl_loss', aggregation='mean')
      self.add_metric(total_loss, name='total_loss', aggregation='mean')
      self.add_metric(reconstruction_loss, name='reconstruction_loss', aggregation='mean')
      return reconstruction
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems off to me. The KLD term of the loss function is supposed to push the parameters of the latent distribution towards N(0, 1) by imposing a penalty proportional to how much the two... well, diverge.

You said you looked at the loss and it seems fine. If I had to guess, there is some kind of issue with its implementation.

The KLD term may not be included at all, or it's artificially low due to some bug, the spikes in the loss may occur only for some anomalous datapoints and get averaged out, or the reconstruction loss turns negative so the gains in reconstruction in training massively outweigh the costs of increased divergence.

Comment: I used the Keras Example of the VAE as my VAE and mostly just changed the conv-layers. I added my implementation to my post. I don't think it is false or am I wrong? Also Keras Example had made some changes to their implementation around a week ago. When I update the way they calculate reconstruction_loss and kl_loss my VAE does not seem to learn reconstructing the images at all.

Comment: Can the epochs of training have a big influence on this matter? I should point out that I use early stopping while training so the VAE does not overfit on the training data. Therefore the Training ends after around 30 epochs in some cases.